# Angular variable only available in view, not controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm using Microsoft's [adal.js for angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js), which logs people in via a long and complicated auth chain and is only germane because when the login process is complete, adal makes the user's information available to views:

```
<p>
    {{userInfo.userName}}
</p>
```

That works, but I don't know how.

I'm using [controler-as](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/) syntax, so if I want to use `$scope` in my controllers, I have to specifically inject it, otherwise it's not available to said controller.

And `$scope` isn't being injected into the controller.

Bearing that in mind, how did the view get a hold of a `$scope` variable if the controller doesn't have `$scope` injected?

Thanks.

EDITED FOR CLARITY. I hope the question makes more sense now.

Comment: The `$scope` gets populated in the controller and displayed in the view, for the view to feed data into the controller you need to use the `ng-model` directive EDIT: removed the link

Comment: You're confused. There is always a scope being created for a controller. Whether the controller chooses to use it or not doesn't matter. All angular expressions are always evaluated on the scope. When you use controllerAs, the controller itself is simply stored in the scope, under the name you choose.

Comment: I likely am confused, but I can only get `$scope.userInfo` if I specifically inject `$scope` into the controller. Otherwise, it's `$scope is not defined`.

Comment: @crowhill that's correct and is expected.  In order to access the $scope in the controller it must be injected.  Otherwise you'd have some magical global variable that would have to change values depending on the context

Comment: Which I get. But being able to use them in views regardless of what's been injected into the controller seems similarly magical.

Comment: Well views are a different beast then controllers.  As @JBNizet mentioned above, the scope is always created but you can choose whether or not to use it in the controller.  The only thing a view has access to are objects attached to the scope

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the adal.js library manages a userInfo object for you on the rootScope.  Unfortunately, this means that if you want to access it in a controller you'll have to inject a scope ($scope or $rootScope) into your controller in order to access it.

Views always and only have access to objects on scopes.  In order to a view to have access to something it must be attached to the view's scope.  I'm guessing the angular developers made the syntax `{{ userInfo.userName }}` instead of `{{ $scope.userInfo.userName }}` because of the above restriction (putting a $scope would be redundant)

If you want to avoid injecting the scope into your controller, you could create a factory that injects $rootScope and provides methods for accessing whatever you need.

Comment: I appreciate the answer.

Comment: "Views always and only have access to objects on scopes." 

Do you have a link to some documentation that might elaborate on this?

Comment: That's something I've learned from programming in Angular for awhile.  Let me see if I can find some official documentation

Comment: The closest I could get to official documentation for my statement: "You can think of the scope and its properties as the data which is used to render the view. The scope is the single source-of-truth for all things view related." [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)